# How to detect if iPhone JUST connected to internet?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, wifi

I need to make some things in my app, once device is connected to wifi. It is not about "does it connected to wifi?", instead "tell me when device connected to wifi, while it was offline before?"

In other words I need to response on event when iPhone just connected to internet with any way.

Is it possible with `AFNetworking` or maybe custom API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift).

In the sample code you will find:

```
import UIKit

let useClosures = false

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var networkStatus: UILabel!

    let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (useClosures) {
            reachability?.whenReachable = { reachability in
                self.updateLabelColourWhenReachable(reachability)
            }
            reachability?.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
                self.updateLabelColourWhenNotReachable(reachability)
            }
        } else {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)
        }

        reachability?.startNotifier()

        // Initial reachability check
        if let reachability = reachability {
            if reachability.isReachable() {
                updateLabelColourWhenReachable(reachability)
            } else {
                updateLabelColourWhenNotReachable(reachability)
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {

        reachability?.stopNotifier()

        if (!useClosures) {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
        }
    }

    func updateLabelColourWhenReachable(reachability: Reachability) {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            self.networkStatus.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } else {
            self.networkStatus.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }

        self.networkStatus.text = reachability.currentReachabilityString
    }

    func updateLabelColourWhenNotReachable(reachability: Reachability) {
        self.networkStatus.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.networkStatus.text = reachability.currentReachabilityString
    }


    func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.isReachable() {
            updateLabelColourWhenReachable(reachability)
        } else {
            updateLabelColourWhenNotReachable(reachability)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will notify me... How?

Comment: But be sure to unsubscribe from Reachability notifications, because you might end up being called too many times that "I have internet connection".

Comment: Yes just test a demo from there.

Comment: How do I get `Reachibility` class from?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Reachability.swift

Answer (score 0):

Simple usage for `AFNetworking`:

1. Add observer:

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("networkDidChangeStatus"), name: AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
   ```
2. Implement custom `Selector`:

   ```
   func networkDidChangeStatus() {

       if AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().reachable {
           print("connected")
       } else {
           print("disconnected")
       }
   }
   ```
3. Start monitoring:

   ```
   AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().startMonitoring()
   ```